# Zsh ssh tab completion not working as expected on OS X

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete

I use Zsh on two different machines (OS X and Ubuntu) and the tab completion for ssh does not work the same way. More specifically hosts specified in the file `~/.ssh/config` is **NOT** used on OS X but it is used under Ubuntu. The exact same `zshrc`/`zshenv` and `~/.ssh/config` file is used on both systems (global configuration files are also ignored) so i have no idea why it does not work.

Anyone got any ideas of what the problem can be? The only difference is the version number, on OS X i got Zsh 5.0.5 and under Ubuntu i got Zsh 5.0.2.

**Update:** I tried Zsh 5.0.5 on Ubuntu and that still works so the different versions are not the problem. I've also downloaded and compiled Zsh on OS X and that still does not work so i know that Homebrew is also not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by removing the file `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. I have absolutely no idea why Zsh had problems with it.